# expand() and select() not working with Breeze WebApi2 1.5.0 and EF 6.0.0

Tags: entity-framework, select, breeze, asp.net-web-api2, expand

I used "Code-First from Database" to create a model on my project. Standard queries (without "expand" and "select") work just fine, but they do not work when including "expand" and "select". What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Here is a code sample:

```
        /**
         * Find charges by location and category
         * @method
         * @param {int, int} locationId, categoryId
         * @return {object array}
        */
        this.filter = function (params) {
            var p1 = breeze.Predicate.create('locationId', '==', params.locationId),
                p2 = breeze.Predicate.create('categoryId', '==', params.categoryId),

                query = breeze.EntityQuery
                    .from(resourceName).expand('ChargeItem').select('id,chargeItemId,chargeItem.name');

            if (params.locationId && params.categoryId) return executeQuery(query.where(p1.and(p2)));
            if (!params.locationId && params.categoryId) return executeQuery(query.where(p2));
            if (params.locationId && !params.categoryId) return executeQuery(query.where(p1));

            return executeCacheQuery(query);
        };

        function executeCacheQuery(query) {
            return manager().executeQueryLocally(query);
        }

        function executeQuery(query) {
            return manager().executeQuery(query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache))
                .then(function (cacheData) {
                    if (cacheData.results.length == 0) {
                        return manager().executeQuery(query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer))
                            .then(function (serverData) { return serverData.results; });
                    } else return cacheData.results;
                });
        }

        function manager() {
            return entityManagerProvider.manager();
        }

    };
```

*resourceName* refers to the Charges function in the Breeze ApiController (for this instance, *breeze/charges*). The Charge table (in the database) has three foreign keys: *LocationId*, *CategoryId* and *ChargeItemId*. I would like to find charges by *locationId* and/or *categoryId* and select charge *Id*, *chargeItemId* and *chargeItem.Name* (Name field in the ChargeItem table). It is not working at all when using expand() and select(). It does not even hit the server when I check the network traffic.

Any questions would be welcome. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can I see your code please.

Comment: @codebased Alright, let me post the code real quick.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that the query is failing and you're just not seeing the error.

Notice that you are not catching an error if the query fails. You have `then()` clauses but no `catch()` clauses.

**Lesson #1 - always check for errors in a promise.**

And why is your query failing? I suspect that you have misspelled the navigation property path in the `expand()` clause.

**Lesson #2 - always use the client-side spelling for property names when composing queries.**

You're evidently using the `NamingConvention.camelCase` to map PascalCase property names on the server ("ChargeItemId") to camelCase property names on the client ("chargeItemId").

You should use the camelCase spelling consistently everywhere on the client ... including in the `expand` clause. I'll be it works if you change the relevant part of your query to `.expand("chargeItem")`

But do first go back and put in the `catch` callback so you can see the error. Then fix the error.

#### Suggestion

I don't know if this is your real query. If it is, you can simplify it substantially by building the query incrementally, perhaps like this:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(resourceName)
                  .expand('chargeItem')
                  .select('id, chargeItemId, chargeItem.name');

if (params.locationId) { 
    query = query.where('locationId', '==', params.locationId); 
}

if (params.categoryId) { 
    query = query.where('locationId', '==', params.categoryId); 
}   

return executeCacheQuery(query);
```

This works because Breeze ANDs `where` clauses together.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It most certainly helps. I use the camelCase naming convention, but I must have forgotten to apply it on the entity in `.expand()`. Thanks for underlying it. Now I have question: Do I need to query `chargeItem` from the server previously before querying the charge by _locationId_ and _categoryId_ in the cache (using `executeCacheQuery(query)`), or do I just use query the charge (using `executeQuery(query)`) in the and breeze will take care of the jointure with `chargeItem` itself?

Comment: The camelCase convention inside `expand()` works, but the results show _chargeItem_Name_ instead of _chargeItem_name_. Weirdo... What could cause it?

Comment: I must assume you're talking about the "chargeItem.name" inside the `select` because the `expand` would not do that to the `ChargeItem` entity properties. The `select` must construct a property name for each property value. The name can't have a "dot" so it replaces the dot in the **server-side path name** with "_" , yielding "ChangeItem_Name", before handing the result on to the `NamingConvention.pascalCase` ... and thus "changeItem_Name".  If you really care and don't like that, roll your own `NamingConvention` using the `pascalCase` source for inspiration. It'll take you all of 10 minutes.

Comment: I should have asked you why you are doing a `select` at all. This query returns a *projection* of `Charge` data, not `Charge` entities. I would **omit the `select` clause** unless I had a really great reason for it.

Comment: In some early versions of Breeze, I was using _chargeItem_name_, but seems like it has been changed to _chargeItem_Name_... In other words, I am going to have to put caps on all properties in the queries that were previously written using the early Breeze. And I do _not_ want to mess with custom naming conventions either. Ugrr!

As for the `select()` clause, the reason why I specify those properties is that I need just them to populate dropdown controls. The _Charge_ entity has lot of properties and foreign keys, and I do not want to retrieve them all.

Comment: Do not understand how spelling if synthetic projection property affects a query. That isn't a queryable property. Please show a sample of what you mean.

Comment: It is most unusual to want BOTH a projection of the parent AND the complete set of child entities (ChargeItem). Most either want a compact format (no children) or they want the complete set. Not saying you're wrong. I am pressuring you to think about it

Comment: In a similar vein, are you certain that shrinking the payload by projection is actually worth doing? Have you measured the benefits or are you guessing? I ask because a projection has its costs too such as complexity and the fact you do not get back entities or their relationships. For ex, the projects results are not entities (although the nested chargeItems  ARE), are not cached, and breeze will not maintain the chargeItems property.

Comment: Well, I am currently working on a project that used a lot of queries with `expand()` and `select()` under breeze 1.2.0. So I upgraded breeze to the latest 1.5.2 version, and noticed that the _chargeItem_name_-like properties could not be retrieved anymore, they could only be retrieved as _chargeItem_Name_ instead. But that's alright, I have already started changing the lowercase to uppercase, no big deal. I guess, the main reason why both `expand()` and `select()` are used is cache size management, especially when using Google Chrome, which allocates only 5MB of cache data.

Comment: Say, I have an _Inventory_ entity that includes _locationId_ and _groupId_, two foreign keys from the _Location_ and _Group_ entities. Now, I have a form that includes a dropdown for locations and a dropdown for groups. When I select a given location (whose ID is locationId), the app should populate the groups dropdown by querying all distinct _groupId_ and _Group.Name_ associated with that selected _locationId_ in the _Inventory_ entity. The query should like this:

Comment: `var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('inventories').expand('group').select('groupId, group.name').where(breeze.Predicate.create('locationId', '==', locationId));`

Then, I will be able to push _groupId_ and _group_Name_ in the groups array to populate the dropdown. This helps me save some cache space. The app has had many issues before, because the cache was full, reason why we want to `select()` only the fields that we need, instead of retrieving the whole entity, especially that many of the entities we work with have more than 15 fields. Hope it is clear enough now. Thanks. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70440/discussion-between-riphamilton-and-ward).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need very little from inventories (which could be big), but you're comfortable getting everything about groups for all groups referenced by the inventories filtered by a specific location. That sounds entirely possible. And you have reason to be concerned about blowing the 5MB max for local browser storage if you're storing cached data there for some reason (I assume that's what you mean by  "Chrome allocates only 5MB of cache data).

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to create a predicate for your `where` clause. It is sufficient to write: `where('locationId', '==', locationId)`.  I think we're done :-)

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance and patience. Thank you. :)